# Mysqli delete row from multiple tables

Tags: mysqli

I am new to using mysqli queries.  I am trying to delete a row from multiple tables using the following code:

```
$del_final = "DELETE confirm, coupon, cpn_image, c_token, deal_24 
              FROM confirm, coupon, cpn_image, c_token, deal_24
              WHERE confirm.customer_id=?
              AND coupon.customer_id=?
              AND cpn_image.customer_id=?
              AND c_token.customer_id=?
              AND deal_24.customer_id=?";

if($stmt->prepare($del_final))
{
    $stmt->bind_param('iiiii', $customer_id, $customer_id, $customer_id, $customer_id, $customer_id);
    $OK3 = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->free_result();
}
```

It seems it only deletes when there is a row in each table with the matching customer_id.  Am I missunderstanding how to do this?

Comment: Your SQL syntax isn't good. Use DELETE FROM table WHERE column=value and use one delete query per table or use foreign key.

Comment: I have alot more tables that i need to delete from so I thought this would work using mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this query is bad, really bad. I suggest you that you make an store procedure with the ID as an input parameter and then use a single delete for every table, that is the way to do it.